# How to retrieve test log from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing

I faced with issue to run unit-tests via Jenkins pipeline. Also I want to make text file with testing results.

Here's my current approach:

```
go test -v ./pkg/... > test_log
```

In this case pipeline fulfills successfully but I can't find "test_log" in Jenkins workspace.
What should I do to fix it? Or maybe there's more appropriate approach?

Comment: I do not know Jenkins but with GitLab I would use Artifacts to save a log file if I need the file. Anyhow, Usually you see the output of the build in CI servers and can download that (which would if you do not pipe the output of go test to a file) contain that

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has an environment variable called `$WORKSPACE`. This environment variable is defined as the workspace path. So you can call your command like

```
go test -v ./pkg/... > $WORKSPACE/test_log
```

This way the `test_log` should be placed within your workspace. You can find it later when you check your workspace (e.g. when you click on the button like in the picture below).

[image: Workspace]

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work for me. Maybe Jenkins forbids to write in Workspace directory.

Comment: The variable WORKSPACE is empty in my case.